# Ray tracer for complicated figures

Tags: ios, algorithm, geometry, raytracing, metal

I have implemented realtime ray tracer with MetalFramework for iOS and it is implemented for following optical prisms like dodecahedron, icosahedron, octahedron, cube, etc. All my figures are composed from triangles, for example cube - 12 triangles, octahedron - 4 triangles. I trace rays and search intersection with figure, then I search how ray moves in prism. Then ray leaves figure and I search intersection with skybox. The problem is in complicated figures. When I test cube fps is 60, but when I test dodecahedron fps is 6. In my algorithm intersection with figure is the same as intersection with any triangle. It means that when I check intersection with ray and figure I have to check intersection with all triangles. I need some idea how to do not check intersections for all triangles. Thanks.

Comment: you need to divide the scene sections and test only objects/triangles inside section intersecting with ray.... there are many approaches for this based on trees but I would prefer make a voxel like grid from scene, grouping triengles to `voxel cubes` and then just trace ray through these cubes and test only triangles listed for hitted voxel cube. This should speed up all considerably

Comment: Thanks. I am not understand how to divide scene. Could you give some examples?

Comment: added answer with attempt to clarify what I mean ...

Answer (score 3):

let say you have world bounded by some bounding box

1. **create grid (dividing this box to cubes or whatever)**

   [image: voxel like map example]
2. **each voxel/cell**

   Is a list of triangles that intersects or are in it so before rendering for each cell process all triangles and store index of all triangles inside or crossing
3. **rewrite ray-tracer to trace through this voxel map**

   So just increment the ray through neighboring voxels it is the same as line rasterization on pixels. This way you have partially Z-sort done. So take first voxel hit by ray and test only triangles contained in it. If any hit on voxel was found then stop (no need to test other voxels because they are farer).
4. **further optimizations**

   You can add flag if triangle has been tested so test only those which where not already tested because many triangles will be multiple times tested otherwise

**[notes]**

Number of voxels per axis greatly affect performance so you need to play with it a bit to achieve best performance. If you have dynamic objects then the voxel map lists computations must be done once in a while or even per each frame. For static scene there is sufficient to do this just once.

Answer (score 1):

To trace efficiently you'll need to use an acceleration structure, for example a KD-tree or a bounding volume hierarchy(BVH). This is similar to using a binary search tree to find a matching element.

I would suggest using a BVH because it is easier to construct and traverse than a KD-tree. And I would suggest against using a uniform voxel grid structure. A voxel grid can easily have very poor performance when triangles are unevenly distributed through the scene or heavily concentrated in a few voxels.

The BVH is just a tree of bounding volumes, such as an axis aligned bounding box (AABB) which encompass the primitives within it. This way if your a ray misses the bounding volume you know that it does not hit any primitives contained with it.

To construct a BVH:

1. Put all the triangle in one bounding volume. This will be the root of the tree.
2. Divide the triangles into two sets where the bounding volume of each set of triangles is minimized. More properly you'd want to follow the surface area heuristic (SAH), where you want to create set of triangles where you minimize the sum of the (surface area of the BVH)/(# triangles) for both sets of triangles.
3. Repeat step 2 for each node recursively until you the number of triangles you have left hits some threshold (4 is a good number to try).

To traverse

1. Check if the ray hits the root bounding box, if it does then proceed to step 2 otherwise no hit.
2. Check if it hits the child bounding boxes. If it does then repeat this step for its children bounding boxes. Otherwise no hit.
3. When you get the a bounding box which only contains triangles you'll need to test each triangle to see if it is hit just like normal.

This is a basic idea of a BVH. There much more detail that I haven't gone into about the BVH that you'll have to search for, since there are so many variations in the details.

**In Short** Implement a bounding volume hierarchy to trace.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I'm not sure that it will helpful. As far as I know it is only for static scene. If I rotate my scene it would not valid. I have only one figure which consist of triangles. If I create BVH and rotate my figure, it would not valid.

Comment: What do you mean by rotating the scene? Do you mean you move your objects around the scene or you are moving your camera? Because if you are moving the camera then the BVH remains valid if you have it defined in world space coordinates which it usually is. If you are actually moving the object around in the world then even the voxel grid doesn't help since you reprocess them each frame anyways. If you only have one object in the scene then you just create the BVH in the object coordinate space then it doesn't matter if you move the object around.